# Find all writable files in the current directory

Tags: linux, bash, file

I want to quickly identify all writable  files in the directory. What is the quick way to do it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
find -type f -maxdepth 1 -writable
```

Comment: It issues a warning about the order of options on my system.

Comment: -writeable  is NOT supported.

Comment: @Pavel, simply swap the `-type f` and `-maxdepth 1` to get rid of the message

Comment: if you remove all writable permission to a file and then use the command, does it still find the file? i am curious

Comment: The GNU `find` command needs the starting directory as its first argument.

Comment: @bignose: No, it assumes the current directory. @ghostdog74: `touch 444 file` or `touch 555 file` or `chown somebodyelse:somebodyelse file` or many variations and it won't find it.

Comment: @Dennis , that's what i thought. hence my question.

Comment: @vehomzzz For some reason the name of the flag is writable - without an e.

Comment: This option doesn't work on rhel5/centos5, but it does on rhel6/centos6
look at the -perm option for centos5/rhel5

Answer (score 19):

The `-writable` option will find files that are writable by the current user. If you'd like to find files that are writable by anyone (or even other combinations), you can use the `-perm` option:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm /222
```

This will find files that are writable by their owner (whoever that may be):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm /200
```

Various characters can be used to control the meaning of the mode argument:

- `/` - any permission bit
- `-` - all bits (`-222` would mean all - user, group and other)
- no prefix - exact specification (`222` would mean no permssions other than write)

Comment: That's a very elegant solution. How do I modify this to find files that are writable only by the owner.

Comment: @kshenoy: One way: `-perm -u+w ! -perm -g+w ! -perm -o+w`

Comment: On Mac or any older Linux variant, use:   find -type f +perm 222

Answer (score 4):

to find writable files regardless of owner, group or others, you can check the `w` flag in the file permission column of ls.

```
ls -l | awk '$1 ~ /^.*w.*/'
```

$1 is the first field, (ie the permission block of ls -l) , the regular expression just say find the letter "w" in field one. that's all.

if you want to find owner write permission

```
ls -l | awk '$1 ~ /^..w/'
```

if you want to find group write permission

```
ls -l | awk '$1 ~ /^.....w/'
```

if you want to find others write permission

```
ls -l | awk '$1 ~ /w.$/'
```

Comment: the tilde is awk's regex operator for "match". much like Perl's `=~` regex operator

Answer (score 3):

`-f` will test for a file

`-w` will test whether it's writeable

Example:

```
$ for f in *; do [ -f $f ] && [ -w $f ] && echo $f; done
```

Comment: Also useless without saying what command these options are meant to be applied to.

Comment: @lexu/bignose - it's a `bash` question. `-f` and `-w` are bash operators. What more do you need ?

Comment: @Paul R: look at murugaperumal's reply .. (your explanation + his example would receive a +1 from me)

Comment: @lexu: this seems overly critical - my answer was perfectly valid and contained all the required information - anyone using *nix must expect conciseness bordering on terseness, or they won't get very far.

Comment: I typed `-f` at the Bash prompt and got a command not found error. /sarcasm

Comment: thx for the edit, -1 removed. sry, it won't let me upvote, dunno why?

Comment: @lexu - thanks - 3 upvotes and 3 downvotes now - I guess I'll have to settle for that... ;-)

Comment: @Paul R, the criticism was because you gave options without saying what command you're referring to. Those options are not "bash operators"; they are options to the `test` command, also spelled as the `[` command.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in shell use

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -type f -writable
```

see man find

You will find you get better answers for this type of question on superuser.com  or serverfault.com

If you are writing code not just using shell you may be interested in the access(2) system call.

This [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/17364/how-do-i-find-all-files-and-directories-writable-by-a-specific-user) has already been asked on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/17364/how-do-i-find-all-files-and-directories-writable-by-a-specific-user)

EDIT: @ghostdog74 asked if you removed write permissions for this file if this would still find the file. The answer, no this only finds files that are writable.

```
dwaters@eirene ~/temp
$ cd temp

dwaters@eirene ~/temp/temp
$ ls

dwaters@eirene ~/temp/temp
$ touch newfile

dwaters@eirene ~/temp/temp
$ ls -alph
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 dwaters Domain Users 0 Mar 22 13:27 ./
drwxrwxrwx+ 3 dwaters Domain Users 0 Mar 22 13:26 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 dwaters Domain Users 0 Mar 22 13:27 newfile

dwaters@eirene ~/temp/temp
$ find .  -maxdepth 1 -type f -writable
./newfile

dwaters@eirene ~/temp/temp
$ chmod 000 newfile

dwaters@eirene ~/temp/temp
$ ls -alph
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 dwaters Domain Users 0 Mar 22 13:27 ./
drwxrwxrwx+ 3 dwaters Domain Users 0 Mar 22 13:26 ../
----------  1 dwaters Domain Users 0 Mar 22 13:27 newfile

dwaters@eirene ~/temp/temp
$ find .  -maxdepth 1 -type f -writable

dwaters@eirene ~/temp/temp
```

Comment: I see  the following error with your solution: find: invalid predicate `-writable'

Comment: sorry had . in wrong place , fixed now, look at man find to see how to user this command

Comment: if you remove all writable permission to a file and then use the command, does it still find the file? i am curious

Answer (score 1):

```
for  var in `ls`
do
if [ -f $var -a -w $var ]
then
echo "$var having write permission";
else
echo "$var not having write permission";
fi
done
```

Comment: don't use ls with for loop to parse file names. also quote your variables in the if/else test.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `find -writable` is that it's not portable and it's not easy to emulate correctly with portable `find` operators. If your version of `find` doesn't have it, you can use `touch` to check if the file can be written to, using `-r` to make sure you (almost) don't modify the file:

```
find . -type f | while read f; do touch -r "$f" "$f" && echo "File $f is writable"; done
```

The `-r` option for `touch` is in POSIX, so it can be considered portable. Of course, this will be much less efficient than `find -writable`.

Note that `touch -r` *will* update each file's *ctime* (time of last change to its meta-data), but one rarely cares about ctime anyway.

Comment: Have you tried `touch` on a read-only file as root or on a file that you own? The ability to update a timestamp does not imply that the file is writable.

Comment: If you're root, read-only files on writable file systems are writable, so I don't see the problem there.

Comment: On redhat 4 I get "while: Expression Syntax."

Answer (score 1):

Find files writeable by owner:

```
find ./ -perm /u+w
```

Find files writeable by group:

```
find ./ -perm /g+w
```

Find files writeable by anyone:

```
find ./ -perm /o+w
```

Find files with defined permission:

```
find ./ -type -d -perm 0777
find ./ -type -d -perm 0755
find ./ -type -f -perm 0666
find ./ -type -f -perm 0644
```

Disable recursive with:

```
-maxdepth 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stat -c "%A->%n" *| sed -n '/^.*w.*/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all files that are writable by apache etal then you can do this:

```
sudo su www-data
find . -writable 2>/dev/null
```

Replace www-data with nobody or apache or whatever your web user is.

Answer (score 0):

I know this a very old thread, however...

The below command helped me: `find . -type f -perm /+w`

You can use -maxdepth based on how many levels below directory you want to search.
I am using Linux 2.6.18-371.4.1.el5.