# Bash: How to list only files with read permissions?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I list all the files with read permissions on current directory ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? List every file and whether it has read permissions set? List only files with read permissions set?

Comment: @EtanReisner List only files with read permissions set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm xxx`

Where xxx indicate the file permission on your targer file, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491985/find-all-writable-files-in-the-current-directory).