# find: -readable: unknown primary or operator

Tags: linux

I am trying to use this command: `find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/oldtext/newtext/g" {} \;` to change some text in my project.

Unfortunately the terminal on macOS keeps throwing: `find: -readable: unknown primary or operator`. I searched on the internet but I didn't find anything yet. Any answer is welcome.

Comment: `-readable` is not a standard thing `find` is _supposed_ to support in the first place.

Comment: For the standard setting out what a copy of `find` should support for the operating system to be able to call itself POSIX-compliant, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html; note the presence of `-perm`, which you can use to test readability and writability. YMMV re: availability of features not specified as part of the standard.

Comment: Arguable on-site duplicate: [find all writable files in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491985) -- the same technique works for testing readability as well.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't really get what you mean by "-readable is not a standard thing find". Do you. know what I should change in order to change the names (from within the working directory)?

Comment: The link I gave earlier -- the pubs.opengroup.org one -- is the standard document describing what features `find` is required to support. `-readable` is not part of it. `-perm` _is_ part of it. So you should use `-perm`, not `-readable` or `-writable`, if you want your code to be portable across all UNIX platforms; and the "find all writable files" link above has an answer that shows how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that OSX is not using gnu find and -readable is probably a gnu extension. You might like to check in the find man page on your MAC to see if -perm option is supported; this way you can make sure that what you are looking for is both readable and writable (hopefully you are not using acl access for your project).
You will need to figure out if you are accessing the files trough user, group or global access permissions but you did say it was your project so I assume you actually own the files. If this is so I suggest you could do something like this:
find ./ -type f -perm -600 -exec sed -i "s/oldtext/newtext/g" {} ;